# Reusing state in React with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see myself using declarations like:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({value: ''});
    
return <InputComponent {...properties} value={state.value} onChange={(event) => setState({value: event.target.value || event.target.checked}
```

Whenever a component needs state I have to rewrite this down and it feels not reusable at all. I looked for render props and HOC, but couldn't reuse state.

I tried creating:

```
const StatefulInput = (InputComponent) => {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({value: ''});

  return <InputComponent value={state.value} onChange={(event) => setState({value: event.target.value || event.target.checked />
}
```

But I couldn't reuse, I got 'invalid Hook', 'render received object not something else' errors and some other ones.

How can I do it? Is it possible to reuse this hook?

Comment: You need to create a context for that, see more https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the boilerplate, you can write a custom hook that holds the state, returning a value and a handler that you can pass to the child component:

```js
const InputComponent = ({ value, onChange }) => <input {...{value, onChange}} />;

const useInputValue = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);
  return [
    value,
    event => setValue(event.target.value || event.target.checked)
  ];
};
const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, inputHandler] = useInputValue('');
    
  return <InputComponent
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={inputHandler}
  />
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Or, have the custom hook return an object that can be spread into the child component:

```js
const InputComponent = ({ value, onChange }) => <input {...{value, onChange}} />;

const useInputValue = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);
  return {
    value,
    onChange: event => setValue(event.target.value || event.target.checked)
  };
};
const App = () => {
  const inputProps = useInputValue('');
    
  return <InputComponent {...inputProps} />
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Also note that there's no need for the stateful value in `useState` to be an object - here, since all you need to store is a *string* (the current value), you can have the state be *just that string*, rather than wrapping the string in an object unnecessarily.

Comment: Is there even a need or possibility of wrapping components in such case? Because I thought of doing so instead of just reusing the function. I want to know if I went the wrong way.

Comment: Do you mean the wrapping of `<input` inside `<InputComponent`? No, that's not needed, I just copied your original code and made up contents for `InputComponent` that can illustrate how things could work. If the `InputComponent` isn't really doing anything else, then definitely drop it and just use `<input>`.